# What is a host server

Tags: php, html, localhost, cpanel, web-hosting

Please am actually a beginner in cpanel, so i try install a script on my cpanel, after uploading the script to my domain directory and was trying to install the s, it was asking about my host server

Please you can check the screenshot here:

[image: Please you can check the screenshot here]

Comment: You tagged 'localhost' here but you didn't try it there?

Comment: If the database is on the same machine as where you uploaded the script type 127.0.0.1 else the IP of the server

Comment: @Attersson so i should use the ip of the server right?

Comment: The answer depends on your hosting provider. Check their help resources for the values you should be using.

Comment: @Hashir yes that is right

Answer (score 0):

Host Server actually mean you something that make connection to your server like the

"Localhost"
"Host ip"

THANKS

Answer (score -2):

Host server is one of the type of internet hosting service which is allows organizations and individuals to make website for them via world wide web.

Comment: If you look carefully at the screenshot in the question, It is requesting for **Database Settings**. Host server in this case is the computer hosting the database server.